# django load data command to load auth users

Tags: django, django-models

```
INSERT INTO `auth_group` VALUES (4,'ascs'),(3,'customer'),(1,'dealers'),(2,'sas');
```

This command create groups on `auth_group` table. But, I need similar command in django in terms of load data.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [fixture and load it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) into your database:

```
[
  {
    "model": "auth.group",
    "pk": 4,
    "fields": {
      "name": "ascs",
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group",
    "pk": 3,
    "fields": {
      "name": "customer",
    }
  },
  # ... you get the idea
]
```

And then `django-admin.py loaddata <fixture_file>`. [See more about `loaddata` also](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture). As the doc says, avoid automatic fixture loading now. You should use a migration for this:

> #### Automatically loading initial data fixtures
>
> *Deprecated in Django 1.7:*
>
> *Deprecated since version 1.7*: If an application uses migrations, there is no automatic loading of fixtures. Since migrations will be required for applications in Django 2.0, this behavior is considered deprecated. If you want to load initial data for an app, consider doing it in a migration.

Comment: @SourabhGupta If you are using Django 1.6 or less, don't bother with this comment. Django 1.7 will be released in few weeks and this is to keep this answer up to date. Migrations will be a way to update models in the future: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 0):

We can use custom load commands to add migration data.

instead of loaddata 
I created my own custom command with name load_migration_data

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.conf import  settings

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.add_group()
```

for more info
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/